# Правильна ли здесь пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Цените то, что у вас есть… Сейчас… Рядом… И никогда не думайте: "А может быть..." Может и не быть… Может и не быть…

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, всё в порядке. Стоит подумать о необходимости стольких многоточий.

Я бы оставила только в двух случаях: Цените то, что у вас есть. Сейчас. Рядом. И никогда не думайте: "А может быть..." Может и не быть. Может и не быть…

Важно представлять, что стоит за многоточием, о чём оно умалчивает. При парцелляции, по-моему, лучше смотрится точка, прерывающая речь.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл предложения трудно понять, я привожу **другую редакцию**, чтобы просто понять сказанное.

**Цените то, что у вас есть. Сейчас. Рядом. И никогда не думайте о том, что только ещё может быть. Оно может быть, а может и не быть...**

**Замечания по оформлению**: а) прямая речь (кавычки, прописная буква) здесь смотрятся не лучшим образом; б) не стоит использовать несколько многоточий, лучше обойтись одним.